# VSCode is auto-formatting multiline to one line code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsx, code-formatting, prettier

I like auto-formatting code idea very much. You can use eslint rules to configure code style you like. But some hidden rule makes what I don't like: inlines document destruction props or jsx template element attributes.

Example (this is how I want it to be).

```
const {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 3,
} = require('qux')
```

And here is how it is reformatted by VSCode or some its plugin (not sure)

```
const { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 } = require('qux')
```

It is absolutely OK in case it is reformatted back to multiline when the line lenth exceeds some specified limit.

JSX examples (tried with a new project generated with use of `react-create-app`).

1. OK, it would be too long line, thus VSCode re-formats it to multiline

   ```
   <a
     className="App-link"
     href="https://reactjs.org"
     target="_blank"
     rel="noopener noreferrer"
   >
   ```
2. Line length wouldn't be longer than allowed, but I still love this style

   ```
   <a
     className="App-link"
     href="https://reactjs.org"
   >
   ```
3. But VSCode/plugin has a different preference and reformats it to

   ```
   <a className="App-link" href="https://reactjs.org">
   ```

I tried to find a specific eslint rule which would be responsible for this behavior, but with no luck (not found). I tried to change default vscode formatter from `prettier` to `null` - no luck.

One more strange thing for me: VSCode doesn't highlights such code snippets which it is going to reformat.

So how can it be fixed?

UPDATE

The only thing I want VSCode to do within such code parts, is just breaking one line to multiline in case the line exceeds `eslint` `max-len` value.

Answer (score 5):

If you have `prettier` configured. Did you try the `prettier.printWidth` property [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

```
{
  "prettier.printWidth": 80
}
```